# Exporting one set of functions from multiple files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've just finished writing a big quickbooks wrapper in JavaScript with a lot of parts in different files, e.g. a file for tax, a file for accounts, a file for auth, etc. I'd like to make it so that developers using this wrapper will only have to do one import that will contain all the functions I've written.

Hierarchy is something like this:

- QbTax.js
- QbAccounts.js
- QbAuth.js

I'd like to have another file, or a way that a developer using this wrapper would only have to import one thing, then be able to call all functions from the above files from that one import.

Something like this:

```
import * as qb from './unifiedQbFile.js';
qb.thisIsATaxFunc();
qb.thisIsAnAccountsFunc();
qb.thisIsAnAuthFunc();
```

What is the best way to approach this?
The only idea I have at the moment is to write prototypes in a file (unifiedQbFile.js for instance) and export those. I'd import all the functions from my other files in that unified file then call them in my new prototypes. That seems messy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have one index.js file that exports all files then you can import that index.js file. I would personally go with this method.

```
// index.js
export { qbTaxFunc } from 'QBTax';
export { qbAccountsFunc } from 'QbAccounts';
export { qbAuthFunc } from 'QbAuth';
```

Now in some other script to import it you can do.

```
import qb from 'path-to-index.js';

// All functions should now be available 
qb.qbTaxFunc();
qb.qbAccountsFunc();
qb.qbAuthFunc();
```